# Laravel job executing multiple times in queue

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have a laravel job as follows:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

use Timeline\Timeline;

class testQueue implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Timeline $timeline, $tag)
    {
        $tagData = $timeline->getTagFeed($tag)->getRankedItems();

        if ($tagData) {
            echo "boom";
        }    
    }
}
```

I'm running it via a route as follows:

```
Route::get('/queue', function () {
    $timeline= new Timeline();

    $timeline->login("test", "testpwd");
    Queue::later(5, new testQueue($timeline, "Testtag"));
});
```

Then on the commandline I ran:

```
php artisan queue:listen database
```

However, that one job is running 255 times instead of 1 times and exiting successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the first 254 times all *failed*?

Comment: how do I know if it's failed? It's just echoing "boom". I'm new to this queue thing, apologies if I'm being dumb.

Comment: Did oyou visit `/queue` for many times, before you start the `listen` command? If so, the previous ones will be executed.

Comment: Besides, try to rewrite the `handle` function as a function that only echos boom but not `getTagFeed` and so on.

Comment: No just one time. There's only 1 entry in the database in the jobs table

Comment: rewrite it to this `public function handle(Timeline $timeline, $tag){echo 'boom';}`

Comment: okay, let me try this

Comment: Still executing up until 255 tries. How does laravel know the job executed sucessfully?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146351/discussion-between-turtle-and-hirvesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues) states:

> Binary data, such as raw image contents, should be passed through the
>   base64_encode function before being passed to a queued job. Otherwise,
>   the job may not properly serialize to JSON when being placed on the
>   queue.

So you shouldn't use `public function handle(Timeline $timeline, $tag)` (or `public function handle(Instagram $currentInstagram, $tag)` in your conversation, as the Timeline or something is binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the job after execution.